# Каково  происхождение  слова  "толика"  из  устойчивого  словосочетания  "малая  толика" ?

Tags: этимология

Comment: Тело: Каково  происхождение  происхождение  устойчивого  словосочетания  "малая  толика"?

Comment: Заголовок: Этимология выражения "малая толика"

Comment: Метки: этимология фразеология

Answer (score 3):

Форма среднего рода единственного числа *толико* широко употреблялась в старославянском и древнерусском книжном языках в субстантивированном значении: `так много, такое большое количество' (ср. церковнославянизм *толичество*). Например, в «Житии Бориса и Глеба»: «Оуне есть мнh единому оумрети, нежели толику душь».

В церковнославянском языке, а затем и в приказно-канцелярском издавна было употребительно словосочетание *мало толико*:"Чем же я его возблагодарю? Ничем другим, как тем, что может, хотя **мало толико** способствовать к вернейшему изображению сего важного для нашей истории события! Таким образом, выражение *малая толика* является устно-бытовым видоизменением церковно-книжной и канцелярской формулы *мало толико*. Сложилось это выражение в среде духовенства и малого чиновничества. В литературный обиход оно вошло гораздо ранее XVIII в.

*[(По материалом "Истории слов" В. В. Виноградова.)](http://etymolog.ruslang.ru/vinogradov.php?id=malaja_tolika&vol=1)*

Comment: А как быть со словом ТОЛК?

Answer (score 1):

Только/толика - скорее всего от греческого слова [**τελικά**](https://translate.academic.ru/%CF%84%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AC/el/ru/) - в конце концов, наконец, самый конец, финал, самый край.

[**Только - нареч. ограничительное.**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1055170) Толковый словарь Ушакова.

Примеры с Нацкорпуса:

> Скоро только прострет кому Христос руку свою, скоро только коснет его перстом своим крепким, аж он из немощнаго стается крепким, из безсильнаго сильным.  Митрополит Стефан (Яворский). Рука Христова, Петру простираемая… (1709)

"Скоро наконец протянет кому Христос свою руку, скоро наконец коснётся, вдруг он из немощного станен крепким, из бессильного - сильным..."

> Статуи ― одна готова и с постументом дубовым, которому длина гданских 6 фус, а другую только делать почели. В. Н. Татищев. Письмо Я. В. Брюсу (1717)

"...а другую только начали делать" - только начали, другая статуя ограничена самым началом; где начали, там и кончили.

**Только необходимо для ограничения края понятия/смысловой фразы, может использоваться как союз или в союзной связке противопоставления.**

> О, смертный! воззри на свою телесность! ты еси земля, прах, сложение стихий, коего дивность толика же в камени, как и в тебе! труп твой, столь благолепый в жизни, жизненныя искры лишенный, есть снедь чсрвию и участок согнития и разрушения.  Но воззри на разум свой всеобъемлющий, ― олтарь тебе готовлю: ты бог еси! А. Н. Радищев. О человеке, о его смертности и бессмертии (1792-1796)

О, смертный! посмотри на свою телесность! ты есть земля, прах, состоящий из стихий, дивность которого ограничена(кончается) же в камне, как и в тебе(в твоем земном теле-трупе)! труп твой, холёный при жизни твоей, жизненной искры лишенный, есть еда червей и участь гниения и разрушения. Но посмотри на разум свой всеобъемлющий, - алтарь тебе готовлю: ты бог и есть!

Но далее, вероятно с легкой руки Тургенева или ещё кого, в оборот входит фразеологизм "малая толика". Которая и начинает существовать в значении **частица**, однако я бы перевёл **"малую толику"** как **краешек**/**кроха**/**капля** - хоть что-то, пусть и малое, ограниченное малым / имеющее конец в малом.

> ...но они спешат узнать - к кому бы обратиться с поклоном; кто тот, который орудием таких милостей? Авось и нам перепадет малая толика? Все ищут временщика, и только одного не видят ― императора и заслуг Карамзина. А. И. Тургенев. Дневники (1825-1826)

Авось нам перепадёт хоть капля(милости)? Все ищут временщика, и в конце концов одного не видят - императора и заслуг Карамзина.

Возможно, толика может быть заменой словам "одна", однако я бы сделал так:

> Грамота № 10, относящаяся к XII веку, найдена в 1973 году: «Сь грамота от Яриль ко Онание. Въ волости твоей толика вода пити в городищяньх. А рушань скорбу про городищяне. Аже хоцьши, ополош дворяна, быша нь пакостил». В грамоте употреблено не встречавшееся ранее образное выражение «толико вода пити», которое надо воспринимать как яркую характеристику нищеты и голода: городищане в волости Анании могут только воду пить, есть им уже нечего.

Хотя вряд ли речь идет о крайнем голоде, а скорее о том, что жить не сладко, а пресно.
Чтобы не прибегать к числительным "одна вода в пити", "питьё ограничено водой(а видимо не вином)", [чьсо ради не воды пить въставъ нъ вино. (ἔπιε) КЕ XII, 52а;](https://old_russian.academic.ru/11023/%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8)(Впредь пей не одну воду, но употребляй немного вина..) Пити - пить воду, вино, зелье, праздновать и тд. Оплош - оплошать - сделать плохо, не доглядеть, укажи на недогляд, ошибку. Укажи дворянину на недочет, расскажи о проблеме, чтобы он не вредил, а вел дела опрятно.

С другой стороны "в конце концов" заменимо на толика:

[Но это в конце концов не поколебало веры Гоголя в свою всеобъемлющую гениальность.](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=Cl4qLAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAKKSnw57C9vgBMglncmNyZWF0ZWRABWoEMC45NXgAMgIIAToBAUInCiUKIwoDcmVxEhwKGtCyINC60L7QvdGG0LUg0LrQvtC90YbQvtCyMAE=#:%7E:text=%D0%9D%D0%BE%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8E%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%89%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C.)А. В. Никитенко. Дневник (1835)

Но эта *толика* не поколебала веры Гоголя в свою всеобъемлющую гениальность.

Видимо из-за особенностей согласования *толика* приобретает значение *частица*.

Слово же **ТОЛК**, что интересно, также заменимо на *в конце концов*:

О чём толкуешь? - О чём в конце концов говоришь/думаешь/рассуждаешь? О чем ты в конце концов?

Не возьму в толк. - Не понимаю до конца. "*Я понял это намёк, я всё ловлю на лету, но не понятно, что конкретно, ты имела в виду.*"

**Толковать - скорее всего ограничивать, оформлять в конечных границах, конкретизировать понимание.** Поэтому толк/толкование - *учение*, *доктрина*. А таже *вывод* на конкретном основании, факте.

> [Всякой толк говорит, что в нем содержится церковь: и один толк другой проклинает.](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CjkqGQoJCLQBEAoYMiAKEAUgAEAFagQwLjk1eAAyAggBOgEBQhUKEwoRCgNyZXESCgoI0YLQvtC70LowAQ==#:%7E:text=%D0%92%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8C%3A%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82.)архиепископ Платон (Левшин). Увещание к раскольникам (1766)

Всякий говорит конкретное, говорит категорично, каждой судит отдельно, что в нём(в этом конкретном суждении) содержится церковь: но один конец с другим не сходится, одно суждение другое проклинает.

> [Токмо сожалетельно, что о том обстоятельнейшаго описания, чим кто свой толк утверждал и оное как опровержено и осуждено, не осталось..](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CjkqGQoJCLQBEAoYMiAKEAUgAEAFagQwLjk1eAAyAggBOgEBQhUKEwoRCgNyZXESCgoI0YLQvtC70LowAQ==#:%7E:text=%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%2C%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%20%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%2C) В. Н. Татищев. История российская в семи томах. Том второй (1750)

Также жаль, что о том подробного описания, чем кто свой вывод *окончательно* утверждал и другое опровергал или осуждал, не осталось.

Касательно [Виноградова](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/wordhistory/330/%D0%9C%D0%90%D0%9B%D0%90%D0%AF):

> Ничем другим, как тем, что может, хотя мало толико способствовать к вернейшему изображению сего важного для нашей истории события!

Хотя мало *ограниченно* способствовать, - не значения теряет при замене.

Единственный пример выбивающийся из этой логики очень сомнительное:

> «Како толма и толика прегрѣшившему, за толика лѣть прегрѣшившему въ едино лѣто и час прощенiю сподоби его (τóν τοσα ぃ τα καì **τηλıκα** ぃ τα πλημμεληκóτα χρóνοıς τοσούτοıς )» (Срезневский, 3, с. 974).

**τηλıκα** - совершенно не ясное греческое слово, которое не ищется словарями, кроме 5 ссылок на эту же самую статью и все на русскоязычных сайтах. Скорее всего является ошибкой. **τηλıκα** - Περίπου 5 αποτελέσματα (0,29 δευτερόλεπτα), говорит греческий гугл, в противовес **τελικά** - Περίπου **22.000.000** αποτελέσματα (0,34 δευτερόλεπτα)